# Push objectIds in an array when checkbox is checked in a React.js Functional Component

Tags: reactjs, arrays, checkbox

I have an array in which I want to push the objectIds whenever the checkbox is checked and remove the ids after admin removes the check-mark from it.

```
<Form.Label>Select Package/s:</Form.Label>
{packages.map((item) => (
  <Form.Check
    key={item._id}
    type="checkbox"
    label={item.name}
  />
))}
```

This is the respnse:
[image]

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to set onChange eventhandler on each list item, and spread the checked packages state:

```
const [checkedPackages, setCheckedPackages] = useState([]);

... 

<Form.Check
  key={item._id}
  onChange={
    (e) => {
    setCheckedPackages((c) => {
       let returnValue = e.target.checked ? 
         [...c, item._id] 
         :
         c.filter(el => el != item._id);
       return returnValue        
      })
    }
  }
...
```

Comment: Nope, it is not working it gives an error like this: `Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression`

Comment: Sorry, needed some time to write it better and to correct it, try now, it's harder without a whole working code! I hope it will work now, see for the filter only to adjust it if needed!

Comment: Thank you for the answer it is working but it has syntax error. There is no need of curly braces after the two arrows and there is no need to declare a variable `returnValue`. This is working ```onChange={(e) =>
                  setSelectedPackage((c) =>
                    e.target.checked
                      ? [...c, item._id]
                      : c.filter((el) => el !== item._id)
                  )
                }```